# How do I configure custom routes in Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

I just stumbled at Phalcon (PHP framework) and it looked so promising I decided to try it.

I searched in the docs but haven't found anything related to routes in Phalcon. Does somebody know how to create custom routes in this framework or am I supposed to always follow conventions?

If you don't know Phalcon yet you might want to [look at these slides](https://speakerdeck.com/embed/4edf11f72a2b980050009919) to see what it's about.

Comment: I looked at their docs. Looks like they currently only have Controller/Action routes. See here http://phalconphp.com/api/class/Phalcon_Router_Rewrite. I was going to look at the code, but I realized the code was written in C, which I'm not too fluent in. See here: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/release/phalcon.c

Comment: I would love to know C and don't need to ask this question here, but it's not an option at moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They replied to the request and have just implemented the custom routes, it doesn't look that good right now but here is the reference:

```
$router->add("/admin/:controller/a/:action/:params", array(
    "controller" => 1,
    "action" => 2,
    "params" => 3,
));
```

Links:

- [Phalcon custom routing documentation](http://phalcon.uservoice.com/forums/154026-general/suggestions/2884092-custom-routing)
- [The request for custom routing feature](http://phalconphp.com/documentation/routing)

Comment: I'd love it if that didn't have to go in the bootstrap, but it's adequate enough for what I needed. The tests I did show the regex based routing to not be any faster or slower than just using `.htaccess` (I was hoping for faster, but not slower is perfectly acceptable).

Comment: I actually just [suggested](http://phalcon.uservoice.com/forums/154026-general/suggestions/3127696-give-more-publicity-to-the-phalcon-tag-on-stack-) that they give more publicity to this tag. Finding what you need in the documentation is rather taxing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to stick with the `baseDir/class/method/argument/...` convention.

I read the documentation and the source code, and I don't see any hint that would allow you to handle custom routes relying only on the C extension. One possible solution would be to map them in .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks @Alix, you're right. I also created a request for this feature and they responded really fast: http://phalcon.uservoice.com/forums/154026-general/suggestions/2884092-custom-routing

Comment: @marcioAlmada: That's good to know, Falcon looks pretty slick. =)